# apt-get install --reinstall failed

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, do-release-upgrade

I just upgraded ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.

But then I realized `iptables-persistent` was missing.

So I decided to reinstall it, using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent --reinstall
```

But it gave me some warning messages :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aptitude-common dh-apparmor g++-4.8 libaio1 libarchive13 libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libboost-iostreams1.58.0 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclass-accessor-perl libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcwidget3
  libencode-locale-perl libept1.4.12 libfcgi-perl libgif4 libgphoto2-port10 libgssglue1 libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libio-html-perl libio-string-perl libisl10 libldb1 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblzo2-2 libntdb1 libonig2 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libqdbm14 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libstdc++-4.8-dev libsub-name-perl
  libtalloc2 libtdb1 libterm-readkey-perl libtevent0 liburi-perl libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvpx1 libwbclient0 libxapian22v5 m17n-contrib mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
  nagios-plugins-common nagios-plugins-standard python-colorama python-crypto python-distlib python-html5lib python-ldb python-ntdb python-pyinotify python-talloc python-tdb rlwrap samba-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,540 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 63410 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../iptables-persistent_1.0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking iptables-persistent (1.0.4) over (1.0.4) ...
Setting up pppconfig (2.3.22) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'S02fw.set' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'fw.set' missing LSB tags and overrides
Setting up iptables-persistent (1.0.4) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S02fw.set' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'fw.set' missing LSB tags and overrides
You have mail in /var/mail/root
```

is this ok? Just wanna make sure everything runs perfectly or not

Comment: The output doesn't include anything suspicious, so you should probably be fine. But I'm confused: If you're _missing_ a package, then you can't _reinstall_ it; you can only do a fresh install of it. Hence the `--reinstall` option is not needed in that case (it would be ignored). The `--reinstall` option is meant for packages that are _already installed_ (i.e., not missing) and for which you wish to run the installation procedure again. Your output looks as if the `iptables-persistent` was already installed (and you reinstalled it), so it seems that it wasn't actually missing at all.

Comment: you're right, I thought it's missing, did `reinstall` just to make sure it exists or not. I was a bit worried about the warning messages, but as you said, I think it should be just fine, thanks for your information

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are related to Ubuntu starting/activating some services during the installation process and are nothing to worry about.

Historically, different init systems have been used in Ubuntu. Nowadays systemd is used, but earlier, Ubuntu used Upstart, and even before that (a long time ago), Ubuntu used SysVinit.

Some scripts may still be lying around in some installation routines that try to use old-school type commands to manipulate services, and when that happens you get the kinds of warnings that you saw. This is nothing to worry about per se: The called utilities (`update-rc.d` and `insserv` in your case) just alert you to the fact that these scripts should be updated, and they revert to some default behavior which should be just fine. If it wasn't and the script actually *needed* to be updated for the installed package to work, that likely would have happened already.

(In your case it looks like `update-rc.d` is called with the `start` option, which is deprecated; it was used to create some symlinks to make some service start in given runlevels. So `update-rc.d` falls back to the command `defaults`, which means that the corresponding service will be started/stopped in those runlevels specified in its LSB header; to do so it uses `insserv`. Two of the services are missing an LSB header, so `insserv` in turn also reverts to some defaults. I'm not sure what those are, but I would assume they'll be ok. At any rate, the worst thing that could happen is that some service is not started at a runlevel where you expected it to run, and that shouldn't be hard to fix.)